# How to go back to previous page

Tags: javascript

I have this part of code where it will go back to previous page after deleting a `comment`.

Is there any way to go back and refresh the page at the same time? Because whenever it goes back, The `comment` is still there since the page didn't reload. I don't want to use a `href` for some reason.

```
if (mysql_query ($delete_query)) {
   echo "<script> alert('Comment has been removed!') </script>" ;
   echo "<script> window.open('javascript:history.go(-1)','_self') </script>";
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use replace method:
window.location.replace(document.referrer)

or assign method

window.location.assign(document.referrer)

Comment: thanks for the help  :)